# Adicionar parâmetros a URL sem alterar o caminho para o ficheiro

Tags: javascript, html, html5, url

Então eu tenho um url imaginemos ...

> http://localhost//web/index.html

A ideia é eu adicionar uma parâmetro ou uma variável a um url:

> http://localhost//web/index.html?like=like

Este parâmetro é escrito pelo utilizador quando define o url.
A ideia é depois utilizar o parâmetro para definir o que irá ser apresentado na página.

O que eu não percebo é: 
como é que ao colocar este endereço...

> http://localhost//web/index.html?like=like

me vai parecer o conteudo que já está em:

> http://localhost//web/index.html

sendo que os url são diferentes...

Eu não quero redireccionar para outra página apenas quero utilizar aquele parâmetro num script mais tarde.

Comment: `?like=like` é um parâmetro do tipo GET e as URLs com e sem parâmetro apontam sim para a mesma página, esse parâmetro mais tem utilidade se você utilizar uma linguagem de lado de servidor

Comment: é possível acessar a string contendo `?like=like` com o comando javascript: `window.location.search`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QueryStrings não mudam o conteúdo da página a menos que o programador tenha feito algo para que isso acontece, logo:

[www.seusite.com.br](http://www.seusite.com.br)

Irá mostrar o mesmo conteúdo de

[www.seusite.com.br?nome=Paulo](http://www.seusite.com.br?nome=Paulo)